# jeditable loadurl: include click id message

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I have use php and jeditable on my webpage and work correctly
But i got a problem in new page

There are many div in the page and the same class ,like this

```
<div id='A01' class='AAA'></div>
<div id='A02' class='AAA'></div>
<div id='A03' class='AAA'></div>
```

i have try store id before editable ()
but i cant find it

```
var idd = $(this).attr('id');
$(".machine").editable("", {
    loadurl : "machsched-machinelis.php?IDD=" + idd, 
    type : "select",
    cancel : "cancel", 
    submit : "edit", 
    indicator : "save..."
});
```

Can i find the click id and send it into `loadurl` ...??

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".AAA").click(function() {

        var idd = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(idd);

        $(".machine").editable("", {

            loadurl : "machsched-machinelis.php?IDD=" + idd, 
            type : "select",
            cancel : "cancel",
            submit : "edit",
            indicator : "save..."
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks nevermind. I have try your code. alert message catch correct id of click ,  but loadurl include idd always is the first click. how to send include the click id of each time click

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
the id is sent to loadrul by $_GET
and sent to save page by $_POST
so, loadrul do not need sent anymore
the answer is so simple

Answer (score 0):

`loaddata` is the solution, URL will like `machsched-machinelis.php?idd=A01`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".AAA").editable("", {
            loadurl : "machsched-machinelis.php",
            loaddata: function() {
            return { idd:  $('.AAA').attr('id') };
        }
        type : "select",
        cancel : "cancel",
        submit : "edit",
        indicator : "save..."
    }); 
});
```